# Анимация изображений

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Под свои нужды делаю своего рода анимированный баннер, который при наведение проигрывает простую 6-кадровую анимацию. Когда мышь отводят, кадры проигрываются в обратную сторону.

Базой анимации выбрал последовательную смену PNG изображений, но есть проблема: если человек быстро вошел в область, затем вышел и снова вошел, анимация начинает дергаться как паралитик.

Как решить эту проблему?

Сама реализация:

```
$(".ban").mouseover(function() {
    var i = 1;
    var objI = $(this);

    function upAnimation() {
       if (i <= 6 && i != 0) {
          objI.attr("src", "animation/0" + i + ".png");
          i++;    
          setTimeout(upAnimation, 111);
       }
    } 
    upAnimation();
}).mouseout(function() {
    var i = 6;
    var objI = $(this);

    function downAnimation() {
        if (i >= 1) {
            objI.attr("src", "animation/0" + i + ".png");
            i--;
            setTimeout(downAnimation, 111);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(downAnimation, 111);
});
```

Comment: html preload images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что все `upAnimation` и `downAnimation` продолжают выполняться (благодаря `setTimeout()`) до самого их завершения. В то время как на самом деле должна выполняться ровно одна анимация.

Для того, что прервать выполнение анимации, можно использовать `clearTimeout(timeoutId)`, предварительно сохранив в `timeoutId` идентификатор, возвращаемый `setTimeout()`.

С этой доработкой (и несколькими мелкими, не влияющими на логику) код выглядит так:

- При наведении и отведении мыши на `.ban` запускаем анимацию вперёд или назад соответственно.
- При запуске анимации останавливаем предыдущую анимацию.
- Во внутренней функции проводим анимацию до тех пор, пока не дойдём в нужном направлении до границы массива (либо пока анимацию не прервёт новая).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var slider = $(".ban");
    
    slider.mouseover(function() {
        animate(1);       
    }).mouseout(function() {
        animate(-1);
    });
    
    var images = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        images.push("http://waytoeast.ru/units/unit" + i + ".png");
    }
    
    var timeoutId = 0;
    var imagesPointer = 0;
    function animate(change) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        (function animateInternal() {
            var newPointer = imagesPointer + change;
            if (newPointer >= 0 && newPointer < images.length) {
                slider.attr('src', images[newPointer]);
                imagesPointer = newPointer;
                timeoutId = setTimeout(animateInternal, 1000);
            }
        })();
    }
});
```

```html
<img class="ban" src="http://waytoeast.ru/units/unit1.png" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

При первичной загрузке картинок возможно их запоздалое появление, но это уже вопрос к предзагрузке картинок.